# Shifting charts

Tags: vba, excel

I created two pivot tables and a chart for each one, no matter what I do the charts are always superposed, I always have to drag with the mouse to see the second chart.
How do i shift the 2? 
**attached the part of the code where I create the table and the chart**.

Thank you

```
 Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=graphe_dos.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Test")
    graphe_dos.Cells(2, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    '**********************************
    '          2nd Pivot Tables
    '**********************************
LastRow = graphe_dos.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Set PTable2 = PCache2.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=graphe_dos.Cells(LastRow + 5, 1), TableName:="Test2")
    'Sheets("Graphe DOS").Select
    graphe_dos.Cells(LastRow + 6, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(204, xlColumnClustered).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the shapes/charts to any position you want

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("ShapeName")
    .Left = 3
    .Top = 2
End With
```

---

Or even

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(204, xlColumnClustered)
    .Left = 3
    .Top = 2
End With
```

should work.